# Trying to get specific field from read in Ksh

Tags: while-loop, ksh

I am trying to write a simple script in Ksh to look at failed attempts and look at the ip addresses. I am dumping a lastb output to a file and want to get just the username tried and the ip address it came from.

the lastb output

```
    user     ssh:notty    143.244.175.142  Mon Jun 21 01:04 - 01:04  (00:00)
    user     ssh:notty    143.244.175.142  Mon Jun 21 00:57 - 00:57  (00:00)
```

my script looks like this

```
    #!/usr/bin/ksh
    FailedLogins="$HOME/sshattempts.txt

    if [ -e "$FailedLogins" ]
    then 
    echo "yes file exists"
    fi

    # while loop 

    while IFS=  read user tty ip
    do
    printf "$user $ip"
    done <"$FailedLogins"
```

Comment: You are missing a `"` in `FailedLogins="$HOME/sshattempts.txt`. I would name the file `ssh_attempts.txt`, now it looks like `ss_hat_tempts.txt` .

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
#!/bin/ksh

if [[ -r $HOME/sshattempts.txt ]]; then
    print "yes file $HOME/sshattempts.txt exists"
else
    exit
fi


while read line; do
    parts=( $line )
    print "${parts[0]} ${parts[2]}"
done < $HOME/sshattempts.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

During processing each line will be parsed into 10 separate (space delimited) fields. When there are not enough variables (3 in this case) the `read` will stuff the 'rest of the line' into the last variable.

Processing the first line from `sshattempts.txt` will cause the following variable assignments:

```
user='user'
tty='ssh:notty'
ip='143.244.175.142  Mon Jun 21 01:04 - 01:04  (00:00)'
```

While you can edit the code to provide the `read` with 10 variables, you can make use of the 'stuff rest of line into last variable' rule by adding one more variable to hold all of the fields that come after the `ip` field, eg:

```
while IFS= read user tty ip rest_of_line
```

Now when processing the first line from `sshattempts.txt` you should see:

```
user='user'
tty='ssh:notty'
ip='143.244.175.142'
rest_of_line='Mon Jun 21 01:04 - 01:04  (00:00)'
```

Answer (score 0):

First and third entry of a line:

```
awk '{print $1, $3}' "$FailedLogins"
```